# Can't upload file to Amazon Cloudsearch with java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I am building a java application in order to index some json files using amazon cloudsearch. I think that I've used correct the aws documentation, but I can't make my application work.

```
package com.myPackage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudsearchdomain.AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudsearchdomain.model.UploadDocumentsRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudsearchdomain.model.UploadDocumentsResult;

public class App 
{
    public static final String ACCESS_KEY = "myAccessKey";
    public static final String SECRET_KEY = "mySecretKey";
    public static final String ENDPOINT = "myDocumentEndpoint";

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY);
        AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient domain = new AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient(credentials);
        domain.setEndpoint(ENDPOINT);

        File file = new File("path to my file");
        InputStream docAsStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        UploadDocumentsRequest req = new UploadDocumentsRequest();
        req.setDocuments(docAsStream);
        System.out.print(file.length());
        UploadDocumentsResult result = domain.uploadDocuments(req);//here i get the exception

        System.out.println(result.toString());
//      
//      SearchRequest searchReq = new SearchRequest().withQuery("my Search request");
//      SearchResult s_res = domain.search(searchReq);
//      System.out.println(s_res);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to unmarshall error response (Unable to parse error response: '<html><body><h1>403 Forbidden</h1>Request forbidden by administrative rules.</body></html>'). Response Code: 403, Response Text: Forbidden
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1071)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:725)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:460)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:295)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudsearchdomain.AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient.invoke(AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient.java:527)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudsearchdomain.AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient.uploadDocuments(AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient.java:310)
    at gvrhtyhuj.dfgbmn.App.main(App.java:31)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to parse error response: '<html><body><h1>403 Forbidden</h1>Request forbidden by administrative rules.</body></html>'
    at com.amazonaws.http.JsonErrorResponseHandler.handle(JsonErrorResponseHandler.java:55)
    at com.amazonaws.http.JsonErrorResponseHandler.handle(JsonErrorResponseHandler.java:29)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1045)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    at com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:422)
    at com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:196)
    at com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:323)
    at com.amazonaws.http.JsonErrorResponseHandler.handle(JsonErrorResponseHandler.java:53)
```

This is the json file:

```
{"a":123,"b":"4 5 6"}
```

Answer (score 1):

First: Please don't put your credentials in your code. It's way too easy to accidentally check credentials into version control, or otherwise post them. If you have your credentials in the default location, you can just do:

AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient client = new AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient();

And the SDK will find them.

One common cause of 403s is getting the endpoint wrong. Make sure you don't have /documents/batch on the end of your endpoint string. The SDK will add that.

One other thing to try is setting the content length:

```
    req.setContentLength(file.length());
```

My code has that, and works, and is otherwise the same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a 403 Forbidden error from CloudSearch, meaning that you don't have permission to upload documents to that domain.

Are you literally using "myAccessKey" as your access key value or did you redact it when you posted this? If you never set it, then you need to set your access key; otherwise check the access policies on your CloudSearch domain through the AWS web console, since it may be configured to accept/reject submissions based on IP address or some other set of conditions.

Comment: I am using my credentials in my code but i preferred to keep them anonymous. I have set my Acces Policies to Allow everyone access to all services.

Comment: What is your document endpoint? Take a look at where they discuss troubleshooting a 403 on this page -- they suggest checking that. Also make sure you have set the access policy for doc submit and not just querying. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/troubleshooting.html